# MySQL failing to start under Cent OS

Tags: centos, mysql

I'm trying to start mysqld on a CentOS box running Plesk as it is failing to start on its own.

Issuing the 'service mysqld start' command consistently fails. The /var/log/mysqld.log contains the following log output that I have so far been unable to diagnose:

```
140812 11:02:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140812 11:02:06 [Note] libgovernor.so not found
140812 11:02:06 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140812 11:02:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.5G
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140812 11:02:06 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: ERROR: We were only able to scan the log up to
InnoDB: 521620455936, but a checkpoint was at 521620456252.
InnoDB: It is possible that the database is now corrupt!
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 5 log sequence number 521796960861
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 311359 log sequence number 521812034102
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 604 log sequence number 521733589779
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 262172 log sequence number 521916027574
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 226339 log sequence number 521733589779
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 393217 log sequence number 521650203404
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 393230 log sequence number 521672783155
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 409641 log sequence number 521858248765
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Error: page 227012 log sequence number 521815629412
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 521620456252.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: End of page dump
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Page checksum 1035077618, prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum 3964970138
InnoDB: stored checksum 1035077618, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 3867662893
InnoDB: Page lsn 121 2063969088, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 2169240268
InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 426042,
InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be an insert undo log page
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 426042.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
InnoDB: error.
InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
140812 11:02:06  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140632717436896 in file buf0buf.c line 3619
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
10:02:06 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=268435456
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=300
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 918492 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x79275e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x67ab83]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710)[0x7fe79ae8e710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7fe7992d6925]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7fe7992d8105]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8101df]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x81dc38]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x81e3ea]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8133b5]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7edf14]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7e3141]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7e3558]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7e6323]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7d233c]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x79ddc0]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x67d8b1]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x590a68]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x8c8)[0x594348]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x51a668]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x3fd)[0x51d28d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fe7992c2d1d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x512915]
```

Edit: my MySQL configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1536M
key_buffer = 256M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 2M
thread_cache_size = 12
max_connections = 300
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100

table_cache = 1600
table_definition_cache = 800

open_files_limit = 2600


innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

join_buffer_size = 2M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8


tmp_table_size = 6M
max_heap_table_size = 6M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

[root@s17111944 ~]# free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3927        470       3456          0         33        231
-/+ buffers/cache:        206       3721
Swap:         2055          0       2055
```

Comment: Can you provide you MySQL configuration file. This one can be found in /etc/my.cnf.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the config file. Thanks

Comment: Do you have enough memory on your server? What says output for #free -m ?

Comment: Main post updated with free -m, thank.